# Numerical Maximization with Alternating Sum

Tags: functions, numerics, mathematical-optimization, constraint

I need to maximize a function that involves an alternating sum and a set of constraints. I have tried the following code:

> NMaximize[{(-1)^{m}*n!, n + m == 7, m > 0, n > 0}, {m, n}]

However, the error message

```
NMaximize: The objective function {(-1)^m n!} should be scalar-valued
```

appears.

Are there any numerical maximization methods that can be used for functions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Change `(-1)^{m}` to `(-1)^(m)` and (2) add the constraint that `m` and `n` are integers:

```
NMaximize[{(-1)^(m)*n!, n + m == 7, m > 0, n > 0, Element[{m, n}, Integers]}, {m, n}]
```

> {6., {m -> 4, n -> 3}}

Comment: Thank you! I am glad it was such an easy fix.

Comment: @smallscot, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.